# WP7 SDK tools can't find device

Tags: windows-phone-7, visual-c#-express-2010

Just went through hell today reformatting my laptop and redownloading Visual Studio for Windows Phone and I've been getting this ridiculous error all day.  When I try to deploy my project on my HTC Radar 4G, I keep getting Error

```
Failed to connect to the device. Ensure that the device is completely booted and is connected to the PC.
```

I registered my device from work about a week ago and was able to deploy a little sample app I made shortly after that, but now none of the SDK tools seem to know what my phone even is.

It started 2 nights ago when I was at work and plugged the phone in and was unable to deploy anything to it, figured it was my work pc or some of the bum USB cables we have so I went home and tried on my personal laptop and still no go.

I've seen a lot of people on forums having this problem and a million snake oil solutions like rebooting the phone, rebooting the computer, unplugging, replugging, reinstalling, and deleting certificates, but nothing is working.

Anyone have any ideas why this phone won't deploy anymore?  I haven't tried a hard reset yet because I have a lot of contacts and stuff to backup and it would be a huge hassle for something that probably won't work.

Comment: Please make sure that your device is connected to PC and your PC is able to detect it. Also, Zune software should be running while deploying.

Comment: Does the Zune software start up and connect correctly when you plug the device in?

Comment: Yes, I've tried on two separate computers and both find the device and automatically open zune.  I've also tried ending the zune and its autostart process and starting them manually.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend using Zune to connect to the phone for development purposes. It has worked on and off for me in the past.

You should use [The Windows Phone Developer Tool Windows Phone 7 Connect Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180729%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). Then turn off the Zune option that tells it to open automatically when you connect the device. It should work good after that.

Comment: I got impatient and hard reset my phone anyway, lost a lot of pictures and such that I thought were on skydrive.  Which did work, but I forwarded this solution to another person having the same issue as me and I'll let you know if it works for them.